# For which p.s.d $A$ is $\alpha HAH \prec HA + AH$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, positive-definite

Suppose $A$ and $H$ are symmetric positive definite matrices over reals. Is there a nice way to characterize the set of $A$ such that following holds for some $\alpha>0$ and given fixed $H$?

$$\alpha HAH \prec AH + HA$$

Two special cases:

1. Any $A$ simultaneously diagonalizable with $H$
2. For any $\frac{1}{9}<x<9$ where $A,H$ are as follows

$$\text{H=}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\text{A=}R
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)R^T$$

$$R=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Motivation**

This characterizes when single step of least squares gradient descent shrinks the error in all directions. IE, take $A=E[xx']$ and ask whether it's possible to tune $\alpha$ to make make $E[yy^T]\prec E[xx^T]$ where

$$y=x-\alpha Hx$$

In the example above, with $x=9$, it's not possible. Even though you can shrink mean error, there's always a "piece" sticking out -- variance grows in some direction.

[image]
[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/math-psd-learning-rate.nb)

Comment: Are you looking for condition on $A$ or on $H$? In other words what is fixed?

Comment: I'm looking for condition on $A$, in terms of fixed $H$

Comment: Okay and $H$ is it positive definite or semidefinite? And $\alpha$ is it fixed as well?

Comment: Given fixed positive definite $H$, solve for positive definite $A$ such that there exists $\alpha>0$ and  $\alpha HAH \prec HA + AH$. When does solution exist?

Comment: I think I understand better the problem. One way to tackle it is to write every thing in the basis of eigenvectors of $H$

Comment: Since $\alpha HAH\prec AH+HA$ for some $\alpha>0$ if and only if $AH+HA\succ0$, you are essentially finding those $A\succ0$ such that $AH+HA\succ0$.

Comment: @user1551 thanks! So following Horn, PSD condition implies that $AH$ is positive stable (the converse doesn't hold unfortunately)

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $H$, we want to solve this optimization problem:

\begin{align}
\max_{A\succeq 0}\; \text{Tr}\left(AH\right) : AH + HA \succeq 0
\end{align}

Which is a easy SDP to solve. A feasible solution of this problem is $A=H$. So the optimal value is of this problem is positive. Let $A^*$ be an optimal solution and $\alpha = \frac{\lambda_{\min}\left(A^*H+HA^*\right)}{\lambda_{\max}\left(HA^*H\right)}.$

Comment: I don't think that's right, should be $\lambda_min((HA+AH)((HAH)^{-1}}$ which is not the same as as your expression

Comment: Is not the same but it works as well.

Comment: Are you assuming simultaneous diagonalizability? It doesn't work for general A,H -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk36K.png

Comment: It does work in general let $B= AH+HA$, 

$$x^TBx - \alpha x^THAHx \ge \lambda_{\min} (B) x^Tx - \alpha \lambda_{\max}(HAH) x^Tx \ge 0$$

Comment: Try your method with $A=H$ and diagonal $H$ with eigenvalues $1,2$, and compare against the other method which reduces to $2/\|H\|=1$

Comment: Yes I am not saying that the other formula does not work. I am just saying that both of them work.